# tabulator.js: Dropdown (editor: select) responsive not working?

Tags: tabulator

I'm using tabulator.js 4.9.3 and I use built in drop down (select) like that editor:"select".

When I'm on full screen desktop I can use it, but in responsive mode with small screen the drop down doesn't work. No drop down list will be shown when clicking on the field.

I tried it on Safari Mac OS.

Is there something I need to do? Is it not working at all?

Michael

Comment: Please include a link to a JS Fiddle that demonstrates the issue and how your table is configured

Answer (score 0):

Only full columns are editable in Tabulator, once it has been collapsed into the responsive list it is a read only value.